# python quits unexpectedly running pyautogui

Tags: python, macos, compilation, pyautogui

I'm running Python 2.7.12 installed with homebrew on my Mac OS X 10.11 and trying to use pyautogui. However, it keeps crashing ("Python quit unexpectedly.") when I try to run it as an imported module in another .py file. Like this:

```
    # gui.py

    import pyautogui

    def myfunction():
        pyautogui.click( 100 , 200 )

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        myfunction()


    # another.py

    import gui

    gui.myfunction()
```

It works fine when I run "python gui.py" alone. But when I try to run another.py, even without calling any function from gui.py, Python would crash every single time. After narrowing it down with line by line elimination, it seems it's the

```
    import pyautogui
```

that caused the crash. Any idea why? All I know is when included as a module, a .pyc file is created. I tried to delete it and run again, but didn't do anything.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running it using python 3.4 ? it is supported all right. Interesting module BTW.

Comment: No. The couple projects I have going right now are written with Python 2. If it really comes down to it, I'm willing to switch, but I"m hoping I don't have to go nuclear yet.

Comment: first which version are you using? upgrade at least to 2.7.10. Then you could define `PYTHONNOWRITEBYTECODE` env. variable to avoid creating `.pyc` (in case this is the problem). FYI works fine here on windows 10 & python 2.7.10. No crashes so far. You could also make a test with pyhton 3.4 to see if it does the same thing.

Comment: I'm using 2.7.12.  I don't know how to set the PYTHONNOWRITEBYTECODE variable but I'm looking it up right now. Thank you for the help by the way!

Comment: you've got a bash shell. Just open it and type: `export PYTHONNOWRITEBYTECOD‌​E=yes`, then run your python script in the same bash (env. vars set that way are not persistent)

Comment: Just tried it. Still the same result. It just won't take "import pyautogui". I wonder if it's because I'm using the non-system python. I installed it with homebrew.

Comment: Maybe there are library conflicts. Yes, you have Python 2.7 in standard as I just read. Try with standard installations.

Comment: Okay I changed my .bash_profile to use the system python. It worked, didn't crash! Yay! So this must mean I didn't install pyautogui correctly, right? I just uninstalled it as well as the packaged it requires( pyobjc, pyobjc-core, etc. ) How do I make sure I install it correctly this time? I don't need a vitualenv, do I?

Comment: By the way, when I intalled pyautogui the first time, I did it using pip, then my python couldn't even find it. So I manually installed it using  "python setup.py install". That got me to where I had to post this question. Maybe this explains something I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got it! This is because I'm importing pyscreenshot, and there is a conflict between it and pyautogui. Both use pillow and probably have some different reference to it that I'm not knowledgeable enough to tell. But as soon as I removed the pyscreenshot, pyautogui is running normal.